# IOS Segue - Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGeneric Exception'

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, debugging, uistoryboard

Storyboard screenshot 
[image: images]

In the Xcode 4.6 Storyboard i've 2 ViewControlers, one which holds the buttons and the other a  labelView, passing a string "Home Tapped" on the tap of the home button

Heres the ViewController.m code

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "ViewController2.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Home"])
    {
        NSString *message = @"Tapped on home";
        ViewController2 *vc = [segue destinationViewController];
        vc.labelString = message;
    }
}
```

ViewController2.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController2 : UITableViewController

@property(nonatomic,strong) UILabel *mylabel;
@property(nonatomic,strong) NSString *labelString;

@end
```

And the error

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Could not find a navigation controller for segue 'Home'. Push segues can only be used when the source controller is managed by an instance of UINavigationController.'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1c91012 0x10cee7e 0x468f31 0x45ab99 0x45ac14 0x10e2705 0x162c0 0x16258 0xd7021 0xd757f 0xd66e8 0x45cef 0x45f02 0x23d4a 0x15698 0x1becdf9 0x1becad0 0x1c06bf5 0x1c06962 0x1c37bb6 0x1c36f44 0x1c36e1b 0x1beb7e3 0x1beb668 0x12ffc 0x28dd 0x2805)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
(lldb)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make your `NavigationController` the entry point for your storyboard. Right now it is `View Controller`, which is indicated by the arrow pointing to it with no source.

Comment: I did but encountered a new error Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UITableViewController loadView] loaded the "7q7-5X-H9Q-view-Zqh-bR-38f" nib but didn't get a UITableView.'

Comment: That is because your second ViewController is a subclass of UITableViewController, but there is no TableView in it. You should make it a subclass of UIViewController

Comment: sure but now i am unable to set the string value to the label